# passing object javascript, sqaure brackets vs . notation

Tags: javascript

can someone explain how to pass an object in JavaScript?
The oject is **this.enemies** and it is passed to createFromTiledObject method via the group parameter.

However, **[group].add(item);** throws an error

```
    this.enemies = this.game.add.group();

 createFromTiledObject: function(element, group, type, enemykey) {
    var item = new SuperSmash[type](this.game,  element.x, element.y, enemykey, 123, this.map, this.player);
    [group].add(item); 

  },
```

Comment: `[group]` what do you use the brackets for?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to do or what `[group].add(item);` has to do with it. (`[group].add(item);` creates an array, with one value in it (`group`), then tries to call the `add` method on it (passing the argument `item`), this throws an error because arrays don't have an `add` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `[group]` is an array literal containing one element `group`. Arrays don't have a method `.add()` so you will get an error when you try to call that method on the array.

Answer (score 0):

Ommited the [] and it worked, thanks for the quick reply